# Can someone give me an example of how -logp(x) works?

Tags: information-theory

I'm studying information theory and I was reading that you receive more information from $-\ln p(x)$ when $p(x)$ is small. So from my understanding from an event happening that has a low likelihood gives a lot of information. How is this information quantified and why does $-\ln p(x)$ of a probability show this? Can someone give me an example to better my understanding?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article [Information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))?

Comment: @gt6989b:  the logs here are usually taken to base $2$, not $e$ as in $\ln$.  That means a coin flip gives one bit of information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coin flip has $p=\frac 12$, so the information it gives you is $-\log_2(\frac 12)=1$ bit.  If you flip three coins and get the result, each result has a chance of $\frac 18$ and $-\log_2(\frac 18)=3$, so you have gotten three bits of information.  We use the log so the information adds when the probabilities multiply.

Comment: So does this just mean we need 1 bit to represent flipping a coin? 0 for heads for example and 1 for tails? Then for flipping we need 3 bits to represent all the possibilities? Is that all this means?

Comment: Yes, it is just a conversion between probability and information.  It describes how many bits of information you need to describe the situation.

Comment: This might be better suited as a new post that you could answer, but the reason behind me wanting to understand this is to understand KL divergence. Cause that relies on the definition of entropy. I was wondering how representing your probabilistic space as bits helps you quantify the difference between distributions.